# How can I add a class to displays a category?

Tags: categories

I am displaying the categories of post through `the_category ();`, and I would like to customize the text, such as changing the color, font-size...

This is my code:

`<span class="post_info"><?php the_category (', '); ?> </span>`

This code only prints the `<a>` tag, without class and without ID.

I looked in the codex of `the_category` and `get_the_category` something about the addition of classes, but found nothing on.

So, how I can add certain `class` to this element?
 How I can add a class to display a category?

---------------------------------- **UPDATE** ------------------------------

This code makes that I want:

```
function add_class_to_category( $thelist, $separator, $parents){
    $class_to_add = 'custom-slug';
    return str_replace('<a href="',  '<a class="'. $class_to_add. '" href="', $thelist);
}

add_filter('the_category', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\add_class_to_category',10,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the_category, I would just build the category links manually and add the category slug as the class name. Something like this:

```
<span class="post_into">
    <?php
        $thelist = '';
        $i = 0;
        foreach( get_the_category() as $category ) {
            if ( 0 < $i ) $thelist .= ', ';
            $thelist .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_category_link( $category->term_id ) ) . '" class="' . $category->slug . '">' . $category->name.'</a>';
            $i++;
        }
        echo $thelist;
    ?>
</span>
```

Comment: The aim of entering the class is just to modify ALL of them at once. Using a `slug` I would have to modify one by one /:

Comment: Why did you need a class at all then if you're going to style them all the same? Why not just target ".post_info a"

Comment: Because of escalability and inside of `<span class="post_info">` I've others tags `<a>`.